# bind a jquery slider to the dom

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, dom

I've got a jquery UI slider in an ajax part of my webpage. if I'm reloading this part with ajax, the slider disappears. I guess I need to attach the slider to the DOM but it looks like it needs an event to be attached on like :

```
$(".radio").on("click", function () {
```

but I don't know which kind of event I need to attach there?

thx

current html:

```js
$(function() {
  var handle = $("#custom-handle");
  $("#custom-handle").text(sizes[0].value);
  $("#slider").slider({
    create: function() {},
    min: 0,
    max: sizes.length - 1,
    step: 1,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      handle.text(sizes[ui.value].value);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider">
  <div id="custom-handle" class="ui-slider-handle"></div>
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: what is "sizes" referring to? Add more html code, your code for the slider and explain the issue [much] more clearly. This is a very vague question as it stands.

Comment: Your example does not appear to contain any AJAX. Please clarify what you mean by *reloading this part with ajax*. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Maybe the success or complete event of ajax if what you wanted. I guess. Please see https://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've got a jquery ui slider in an ajax part of my webpage. if I'm
>   reloading this part with ajax, the slider disappears.

Are you replacing the slider HTML code in ajax? i.e. are you replacing this div?

```
<div id="slider">
  <div id="custom-handle" class="ui-slider-handle"></div>
  <br>
</div>
```

If that is the case, then I don't think the problem is with binding... have you tried reinitialize the slider once the ajax call is completed?

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'some url',
    success: function(data) {                       
        initializeSlider();
    }
});      

function initializeSlider() {
    $("#slider").slider({
        create: function() {},
        min: 0,
        max: sizes.length - 1,
        step: 1,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            handle.text(sizes[ui.value].value);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thx that was it, sry for delay i will award a new bounty after 23h00 delay